How to wrap CKEditor 5 editor in a custom div?
Migration from CKEditor 4 page, under the BodyClass section, states I can wrap the editor in my own div. "Simply wrap the editor with a <div class="...">", but, how?
In CKEditor 4 I used the BodyClass setting in hook_editor_js_settings_alter to add a custom class to the editor. CKEditor 5 removes BodyClass and says to wrap the editor in a div with my class, but how to do this in Drupal?
